# issues with Xcode 4.5 while changing iPad's orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Am facing this problem ever since i upgraded to XCODE 4.5.

I have various UI elements

`UIButton *button1;
UIButton *button2;
UIButton *button3;`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    button1 =[[UIButton alloc]init ];
    button1.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
[self.view addSubview:button1];


button2 =[[UIButton alloc]init ];
button2.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
[self.view  addSubview:button2];


button3 =[[UIButton alloc]init ];
button3.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
[self.view  addSubview:button3];
}
```

whose frames are declared in

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {  
 if(interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||[interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
 {


 button1.frame=CGRectMake(10,10,10,10);
 button2.frame=CGRectMake(10,30,10,10);

 button3.frame=CGRectMake(10,50,10,10);
 }
      if(interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
 button1.frame=CGRectMake(20,10,10,10);
 button2.frame=CGRectMake(20,30,10,10);

 button3.frame=CGRectMake(20,50,10,10);
  }

 return YES;

}
```

but the frames are not set in Xcode 4.5..
in the previous versions it worked fine.

i need auto sizing badly in my app. so help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should need to implement new methods(introduced in 'ios 6' ) in viewController for orientation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

    return TRUE;
```

}

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;


}
```

And Modify You Code place your code inside the in Below Method

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)  interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

 }
```

Also check your window, you need to add the controller on window as rootviewController rather than addSubview like below

self.window.rootViewController=viewController;

Comment: this one works.. :) thanks a ton.

but apart from this will u be able to give me some links or reference to the changes and new methods came with ios 6

Comment: Search for shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in the iOS 6 documentation (Organizer -> Documentation in XCode), you should get to a "Deprecated in iOS 6"-page where it states that shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: is deprecated and what has replaced it.

Answer (score 1):

**Some classes  will automatically resize when the device orientation changes,** e.g. from portrait to landscape, but others (like UILabel and UITextView) require a little configuration.

The **setAutoresizesSubviews** property controls whether each object will resize automatically when their bounds change.

The **setAutoresizingMask** property controls how each object resizes automatically. A UILabel only has to worry about resizing its width, but since a UITextView is scrollable it needs to resize both its width and height when its bounds change.

You should also make sure the **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation** method is configured to return **YES**; otherwise your view won’t do anything when the device orientation changes!

**Sample Code:**

```
[self.myLabel setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
[self.myLabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

[self.myTextView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
[self.myTextView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

**For more details you can visit** [here](http://userflex.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/autoresize-uiview-orientation/)